# I want to show event date with marker in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2, marker

I am using PHP and MySQL to show my all events photos and videos. I want the event date will show with the marker and after click on the marker all photos and videos will show. I can show photos and videos, but I cant show the date with the marker.

So please help.

```
function load() {
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {

        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(xx.xxxxxx, xx.xxxxxx), 8);
        -----------------------------------------------------
        -----------------------------------------------------
        var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            var marker = createMarker(point, name, address, type, photo);   
            map.addOverlay(marker);
    }
}

function createMarker(point, name, address, type, photo) {
    var marker = new GMarker(point, customIcons[type]);
    var html = "<h1 style='text-align: center;'>" + name + "</h1> <br/>" + photo;
    GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
    });
    return marker;
}
```

Comment: Yikes, this is Google Maps API v2, which is very outdated, and should be written to use API v3.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v2tov3

Answer (score 0):

From this [Google documentation example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels), you can see that you can put a label to each marker with a single alphabetical character.

> ```
> var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
> var labelIndex = 0;
> ```

You can also check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056330/how-to-display-a-label-next-to-a-marker-for-google-maps) which might help.

> There's a good label class [here](http://sub1.econym.org.uk/gmap/elabel.htm), though you'll have to add it alongside the markers.

Basically, you can use [ELabel](http://sub1.econym.org.uk/gmap/example_elabel.htm) which allows you to place text labels or images or any other HTML elements on the map and have them move with the map, like marker and polyline overlays.