# Adding labels to custom markers that look and feel like places

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm adding custom markers to my map using the `new google.maps.Marker()` JavaScript API method to map a custom list of locations.

Is it possible to add labels to the markers as shown in this screenshot?

The Marker documentation seems to allow this, but the label that's rendered runs into/overlaps with other markers and labels (I think the property is meant to label the marker itself ('A', 'B', 'C', etc).)

[image: Example]

Here's an example of what I mean by "Labels overlapping with other markers and labels":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you are using custom markers, it is possible. [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#complex_icons) says:

> If you are using a label with a custom marker, you can position the
>   `label` with the `labelOrigin` property in the `Icon` object.

See [this working jsbin](https://jsbin.com/memuxifife/edit?html,console,output) based off of Google's example for demonstration and guidance. Relevant code below:

```
  var image = {
    // here's the labelOrigin
    labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(70, 10)
  };

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     // set the marker's icon to the above image
     icon: image,
     // set a label
     label: {
       color: "black",
       text: "label text here"
     }
  });
```

**Edit**

To add a text outline to the label, see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22333457/11742502) for related thread [How to display a label next to a Marker for Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1056330/11742502) and [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sj91ntz3/) based off of it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this, but the labels run into one another, and there's no way to add a custom class to style the text with a while outline.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by labels running into one another? As for text outline please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks @johnwp can you please post a jsfiddle so that i can reproduce this from my side?